# How to copy data from closed worksheets in folder when sheet name changes?

Tags: excel, vba

I have set up a macro that runs when a button is clicked. The macro checks a specified folder and pulls in the data from all of the workbooks contained in the folder into the active workbook.

The code worked perfectly however, there are new worksheets being added where the tabs have slightly different numbers at the beginning meaning the code no longer works.

Is there a way to make the macro collect all data regardless of the sheet name? (There will only ever be one sheet per workbook)

I have written the code which worked when the sheet name was always the same, however, when this changes the code no longer runs.

```
Do While Len(fl) > 0
' Open file
Set dWb = Workbooks.Open(fDir & fl)
' Copy data from
dWb.Sheets("DailyReport").Range("A2:AU100").Copy mSh.Cells(1, nxtCol)
' Close workbook
dWb.Close SaveChanges:=True
' Increment column counter
nxtCol = nxtCol + 7
' Go to next file
fl = Dir
Loop
```

Run-time error '9':
Subscript out of range

Comment: Change `dWb.Sheets("DailyReport").Range("A2:AU100").Copy mSh.Cells(1, nxtCol)` to `dWb.Sheets(Sheet1.Name).Range("A2:AU100").Copy mSh.Cells(1, nxtCol)`

Comment: I'd replace `Sheets(Sheet1.Name)`  with `Sheets(1)`, just because there's only a single sheet doesn't mean the object name is always Sheet1.

Comment: If there is **only** 1 worksheet, then you can use also, instead of `dWb.Sheets("DailyReport")`, try `dWb.ActiveSheet`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is only one sheet:

```
Set dWb = Workbooks.Open(fDir & fl)
dWb.Worksheets(1) 'this selects the first sheet in the workbook
```

I hope this helps

Comment: If this answers your question, please don't forget to accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try use activeSheet; hard or str variable:

```
dWb.Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name)

Dim ash as String
ash = ActiveSheet.Name
dWb.Worksheets(ash)
```

Comment: This is all working perfectly now but I have hit another problem. I cannot change the data fro all of the sheets to paste into rows rather than columns? Do I have to start a new question for this?

Comment: @kirsten2911 *Do I have to start a new question for this?* Yes

Comment: `ash = ActiveSheet.Name` will return the name of the ActiveSheet of the ActiveWorkbook, which may be a different one than `dWb`, and your code would fail. It should be `ash = dWb.ActiveSheet.Name`